# How to store a browser-wide localStorage value?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, local-storage, tracking

Say I open Chrome and hop into the javascript console. If I run

```
localStorage.setItem('test', 'THIS IS A VALUE');
```

and then close the browser, re-open it, then run

```
localStorage.getItem('test');
```

the result will be, predictably 'THIS IS A VALUE'. However, if I were to navigate to a different page that I was on when I opened the browser, ie NOT on about:blank; or whatever homepage it might be, running .getItem will result in a null.

It seems like localStorage is specific to a certain page. Is there a way to store a value on one page that will work on ANY page?

Say that I want to generate an ID on one page, and then check for the same one on a totally unrelated site, is this possible? Sounds like a bit of a security risk now that I've typed it out.

Comment: Local storage is domain-restricted for security reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a separate LocalStorage store per-domain, much like cookies. Consider the alternative: if LocalStorage were global, different web sites could read and write each other's stored values.

Storing persistent data that "tracks" the user across multiple sites is, somewhat intentionally, difficult. You will need to explicitly take an action that crosses domains (e.g, loading content from, or posting data to, another site) to achieve this.

Comment: I hope this is the right place to make a note. There is a way around this issue. If you're using a browser extension or a framework, such as Kango, it's possible to set a permanent, cross-domain browser-wide value using the extension's API. Obviously this only works if you can get the client to install something which won't work for 99% of people who'd look into this